# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print filtered sub_location drop down according to location attribute form extended admin user in Django.
I have a view which displays a form and saves the same form. There is no problem showing the view but when saving I get this following error:

*TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'*

Here is my code:-

**MODEL:**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubLocation(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AdminProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for Python 2
        return self.user.username


class Batch(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    sub_location = models.ForeignKey(SubLocation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    batch_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.batch_name
```

**FORM:**

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('sub_location', 'batch_name')
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sub_location'].queryset = SubLocation.objects.filter(location = Subquery(AdminProfile.objects.filter(user = user).values('location')))
```

**VIEW:**

```
def add_batch(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        msg = ""
        if request.method == "GET":
            batch_form = BatchForm(user=request.user)
        else:
            batch_form = BatchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if batch_form.is_valid():
                try:
                    obj = batch_form.save(commit=False)
                    #logined admin location will be here

                    admin_object = AdminProfile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
                    obj.location = admin_object[0].location
                    obj.save()

                    batch_form = BatchForm()
                    msg = "Batch Added successfully....!"
                except IntegrityError as e:
                    msg= "Batch already exist...!"
            else:
                batch_form = BatchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        return render(request, 'add_new_batch.html', {'batch_form':batch_form,'msg':msg})
    else:
        return redirect('admin_login')
```

when I am clicking on submit button to save the form then I'm getting this error
**ERROR**

```
Internal Server Error: /admin_panel/add_batch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\monu\Desktop\Task\AdminPanel\views.py", line 34, in add_batch
    batch_form = BatchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  File "C:\Users\monu\Desktop\Task\AdminPanel\forms.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.fields['sub_location'].queryset = SubLocation.objects.filter(location = Subquery(AdminProfile.objects.filter(user = user).values('location')))
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\monu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'
[25/Mar/2019 09:31:03] "POST /admin_panel/add_batch HTTP/1.1" 500 125516
```

Comment: you are not providing user argument when instantiating batch form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided a user argument in your form's init method. In a couple if your else clauses you are not providing this user when instantiating the form:

```
else:
        batch_form = BatchForm(request.user,request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: if I'm adding user=request.user then it is giving:
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

```
batch_form = BatchForm(user=request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: also ,give  SubLocation.objects.filter(location = Subquery(AdminProfile.objects.filter(user = user).values('location'))).first()

Comment: @MonuprasadGaud try rearranging the fields

Comment: SubLocation.objects.filter(location = Subquery(AdminProfile.objects.filter(user = user).values('location'))).first()

gives:
AttributeError: 'SubLocation' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: When I'm rearranging the parameters like this:
```
    batch_form = BatchForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
```
then it is giving this exception:
```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem,

What I did was put it as a keyword between *args and **kwargs and it worked for me!

Based of your code, try this!

```
 batch_form = BatchForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
```

in your views.py

and

```
 def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
     super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['sub_location'].queryset = SubLocation.objects.filter(location = 
     Subquery(AdminProfile.objects.filter(user = user).values('location')))
```

in your forms.py